# Why is GCC complaining about missing identifiers before a 'sizeof' that doesn't exist?

Tags: gcc, gtk, cross-compiling

I'm in the process of cross-compiling GTK+ 3.4.4 for Windows. I have already cross-compiled all of the build dependencies for GTK (ATK, Cairo, GDK Pixbuf, and Pango) and installed them to `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/`.

Attempting to compile GTK itself, however, results in the following error:

```
In file included from gdkrgba.c:31:0:
fallback-c89.c:40:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'sizeof'
fallback-c89.c:40:1: error: expected ')' before '==' token
```

Line 34 - 44 of `gdk/fallback-c89.c` contains:

```
34.  #ifndef HAVE_ISINF
35.  /* Unfortunately MSVC does not have finite()
36.   * but it does have _finite() which is the same
37.   * as finite() except when x is a NaN
38.   */
39.  static inline gboolean
40.  isinf (double x)
41.  {
42.      return (!_finite (x) && !_isnan (x));
43.  }
44.  #endif
```

I haven't the slightest idea where GCC is finding '`sizeof`' or '`==`'. Why is the compiler throwing such a cryptic error message and how can I fix it?

---

**Edit:** here is the actual command line:

```
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..
  -DG_LOG_DOMAIN="Gdk" -DGDK_COMPILATION -I.. -I../gdk -I..
  -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -mms-bitfields
  -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/pango-1.0
  -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/glib-2.0
  -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include
  -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/cairo -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/pixman-1
  -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/freetype2
  -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/libpng15
  -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -O2 -Wall -mms-bitfields -MT 
  gdkrgba.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/gdkrgba.Tpo -c gdkrgba.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o
  .libs/gdkrgba.o
```

---

**Further edit:** after compiling with the `-E` option, I captured the following pre-processed output... which explains the strange `sizeof`:

```
# 39 "fallback-c89.c"
static inline gboolean
((sizeof (double x) == sizeof (float) ? __fpclassifyf (double x) : sizeof double x)) == (0x0100 | 0x0400))
{
  return (!_finite (x) && !_isnan (x));
}
```

I can only conclude that `isinf` is already a defined macro. It is merely being expanded when used in the function declaration above.

My question now becomes... why is `HAVE_ISINF` not defined? Is it a problem with the configure script?

---

**Yet another edit:** okay, so I decided to search for everything in the build tree that contained the string '`HAVE_ISINF`' and came across the following instances:

- autom4te.cache/traces.1

  ```
  m4trace:configure.ac:740: -1- AH_OUTPUT([HAVE_ISINF], [/* Define to 1 if you
    have the `isinf\' function. */
  @%:@undef HAVE_ISINF])
  ```
- config.h.in

  ```
  /* Define to 1 if you have the `isinf' function. */
  #undef HAVE_ISINF
  ```
- config.h

  ```
  /* Define to 1 if you have the `isinf' function. */
  /* #undef HAVE_ISINF */
  ```

Surprisingly, there is nothing in `config.log` mentioning `HAVE_ISINF'.

---

**(Possibly) final edit:** I did some more investigation and found the string 'isinf' in `autom4te.cache/output.0` here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1154478/

This code made a reference to `ac_fn_c_check_func`, so I dug up the [source for that function](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus/libcilkrts/configure) and compiled [the `.c` sample that the script generates](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1154489/):

```
test.c:25:6: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘isinf’
  [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccLYd1R8.o:test.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_isinf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is odd since my explanation above would suggest that `isinf` is simply a macro.

Comment: I think the first thing to do here is to build that file with all the relevant compile options plus `-E`, to generate the preprocessed source output. There may be a preprocessor `#define` that is confusing the issue.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Good idea... I'm not 100% sure how to do that however. GTK+ is using autotools and the individual commands aren't printed to the terminal. Is there some way I can find out what command is used to build it?

Comment: Hm, usually `make` shows the commands, but there's an option to turn that off (don't understand why people like to do that, and this is why). One trick I use sometimes is to make a script called `gcc` that exists in `$PATH` before the real compiler, which saves the command line and then calls the real one.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Good idea. I'll try that. (Before reading your comment, I discovered that `make` has an option `-d` that prints debug information... but that didn't help.)

Comment: also how about throwing an #error at fallback-c89.c:40 and checking any discrepancy in the line-numbers reported in the compile error?...

Comment: When using `-E` to track down a rogue macro, I like to add `-dD` (keeps the `#define`s in the output) and `-C` (keeps comments in the output).

Comment: @GregHewgill: Okay, I've found the actual command being run.

Comment: Great, now run that with `-E` instead of `-o` and capture stdout. That will be the preprocessed source, which is where you might find the mystery `sizeof`.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Nothing gets printed when I use that option.

Comment: Oh, if you've still got `-o` in there then the preprocessed output will go to `.libs/gdkrgba.o`. Otherwise, it goes to stdout. I think. You might have to fiddle with the options a bit to make it work.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Part of the mystery is now solved. Apparently a macro is defined with the same name. Please see my question.

Comment: There should be a `config.log` which you can search for the test that resulted in `HAVE_ISINF` being undefined.

Comment: @AlanCurry: No instances of 'HAVE_ISINF' in `config.log` sadly. I've added some more information to the question though.

Comment: widen your search to any mention of `isinf`

Comment: @AlanCurry: I found `autom4te.cache/output.0` mention something about `isinf`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1154478/

Comment: @AlanCurry: I've updated the question (again).

Comment: So to summarize, mingw is providing `isinf` as a macro but not as a function, and autoconf is confused. It looks very similar to [this python bug report](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.autoconf.general/month=20081201/page=1) where a fix was suggested 4 years ago. Seems like gtk needs the same fix.

Comment: The code in `fallback-c89.c` could be written as: `static inline gboolean (isinf)(double x) { ... }`, where the token after `isinf` is not an open parenthesis, so it is not a macro invocation.  This is a standard technique for neutering function-like macros.  It doesn't work with object like macros: `#define isinf _IsInfinite` would see the reference to `isinf` and replace it.  Arguing against this is the fact that there should always be an actual function for any function defined in the C standard, and the configuration should not be compiling the fallback code if it isn't actually needed.

Comment: @AlanCurry: I finally found an answer and it's similar to what you just described. Please see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found [this](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/scm-commits/2012-July/817348.html). In summary:

> "The isnan() and isinf() are C99 macros not functions so use AC_CHECK_DECL instead of AC_CHECK_FUNCS for those."

So it looks like I'll be patching the source.

Comment: You did it again, thank you ! Good luck too all fellows compiling the gtk 3.4 on mingw !